# Figuring Out How To Access Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have an advertiser model and an experiment model. I've setup the
associations as follows:

```
Advertiser has_many :experiments

Experiment belongs_to :advertisers
```

The experiments table has a column titled **"experiment_type"**, which can
either be **AOV** or **Conversion**. I am trying to display experiments for the
particular advertiser by experiment_type.

I can successfully display ALL of the experiments by advertiser with the
following iteration

```
<% @advertiser.experiments.each do |experiments| %>
 <td><%= experiments.id %></td>
 <td><%= experiments.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Or I can successfully display all the experiment_type with the following
iteration

```
<% @aov.each do |experiments| %>
 <td><%= experiments.id %></td>
 <td><%= experiments.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

What I cannot figure out is how to show the experiment_type by
advertiser. I thought something like

`<% @advertiser.aov.each do |experiments| %>` would work, but it gives me
an

> undefined method `aov' for #

The aov action within my experiments controller is

```
def set_aov_experiments
    @aov = Experiment.where("experiment_type = ?", "AOV")    
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because aov is not a method of the Model entity Advertiser.

If you want to use it like this, place this on your Advertiser Model:

```
def aov
  experiments.where(experiment_type: 'AOV')
end
```

Comment: I added that to the Advertiser model and now can call the iteration with no errors. `<% @advertiser.aov.each do |experiments| %>`. It displays all of the AOV experiments, not for the particular advertiser. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I updated the post, now it only queries in the current Advertiser experiments.